# Merge two fields in one in a Django Rest Framework Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework authentication system which comes with a default user table. In that table it splits first and last name in two different char fields.

Is it possible to join these two fields in a serializer? Something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name' + ' ' + 'user.last_name')
```

So that I would get the following response:

```
{
    full_name: "firs_name last_name"
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can create method in your serializer and show it by `SerializerMethodField`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_full_name(self, obj):
        return '{} {}'.format(obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add two or more payloads into one with this approach?

Answer (score 4):

@Ivan semochkin's answer works if the `full_name` is a read-only field but in my case I allow users to set full name so had to create a custom field and it works in both cases.

```
class FullNameField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.get_full_name()

    def to_internal_value(self, full_name):
        fname, lname = full_name.split(' ')
        return {'first_name': fname, 'last_name': lname}
```

Now include this field in your serializer.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = FullNameField(source='*')
```

Comment: This reponse could be improved because
1) ret is not defined
2) value.get_full_name() - might be mention which method is that (I guess model method)

I gave +1 anyway because it was helpful and works for me (read + set value) ;)